# An adverb or adjective for the mentioned context?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

Many times when someone tells us something we just accept it. We don't consider the question "whether it is true". Perhaps because we trust the speaker. In such cases:

We believe others _____ .

Our acceptance of what other tell us is ______ .

unreflectively/unreflective? non-reflectively/non-reflective? non-speculatively/non-speculative? Immediately/immediately.

"uncritically" sounds to me too strong for such cases.

Comment: It is quite ambiguous what you want / need. I have in mind **wishful(ly)** or **optimistic(ally)**. Maybe **trusting(ly)**. Or **careless(ly)**, **blind(ly)**

Comment: Or perhaps **casual(ly)**, or **unthinking(ly)** or **without thinking**.

Answer (score 1):

"Implicitly" first comes to mind:

> **[implicit](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/implicit)** (adj): 3. With no qualification or question; absolute, *"an implicit faith in God"*

"Implicitly" suggests that the belief is not subject to the usual criticism or doubt, regardless of any contrary argument or evidence.

> Many GOP voters seem to **implicitly** believe that Donald Trump is good for the party and good for the nation.

Other possibilities:  *completely, unquestioningly, unreservedly, invariably, unshakably*, etc.